# Using cURL in a foreach-loop (php)

Tags: php, curl, foreach, php-curl

I have many HTTPS-URLS where I have to find a Special Phrase, so I´m trying to use cURL in a foreach Loop, but it´s not working.

```
...
foreach($sites as $site) {

    $URL = $site;        

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

}

print substr($response, $start, $i);
...
```

If I use just a single HTTPS-URL I get the Phrase, but inside a foreach-loop it´s not working.
Can someone help me? (:

Please excuse my poor english..

Comment: Is there some warning/error? If not, maybe they're turned off from the `php.ini` file that is used. Make sure they're turned on and check for any notices/warnings/errors.

Comment: For people with a bit like my case. In my case, I have placed the curl code with a return statement in a function and called that function in foreach loop. So when the first call was done, the return statement was executed and the loop was stopped. I have put the return statement in a if condition for specific calls, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this may help :) store result inside an array

```
$sites = ['https://stackoverflow.com','http://example.org'];
$result = [];
foreach ($sites as $site) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "PHP Curl");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // execute the given URL, and return output
    $result[] = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);


}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Yeah ! Thank you <3

Comment: Hi. What if I have like 10000 reigsters on the $sites array, and the function times out after 60 seconds? How can I make sure all the cURL requests were sent?