# How to use cURL in for loop?

Tags: php

My for loop can run twice, but it only run once when I use the cURL in for loop
My for loop can run twice, but it only run once when I use the cURL in for loop

```
public function index_onSync () {

    $checkedIds = post('checked');

    $data = ModelsAdmin::select('id', 'address', 'private_key')->whereIn('id', $checkedIds)->get();

    $sync_data = array();  

    for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

        $url_confirm = "http://127.0.0.1:50233/sync";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_confirm);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        $post_data = array( "id"=>$data[$i]['id'], "address"=>$data[$i]['address'], "private_key"=>$data[$i]['private_key'] );
        $json_data = json_encode($post_data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($json_data)
        ));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json_data);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = json_decode($data);  
        array_push($sync_data, $data);

        echo $data;

        curl_close($ch);

    }

    var_dump($sync_data);
}
```

Comment: Should `$i < count($data);` actually be `$i <= count($data);`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cURL in a foreach-loop (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623277/using-curl-in-a-foreach-loop-php)

Comment: So you only get ONE outout from `echo $data` is that right

Comment: I see my node.js ,it only called once,and the echo in php also called once

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding your `$data` array from `ModelsAdmin::select` in line

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

So, on the second iteration, your data is not a 2-rows array anymore...
Instead of `$data`, you could use `$response`, for example...

Comment: The main problem is the for loop was only run once,because I see my node.js ,it only called once,and the echo in php also called once